# derive $\delta _{tt} y=y$ without guessing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have a second order differential equation $\delta _{tt} y=y$

We can on the basis of our intuition say that the functions $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ satisfy this second order ODE. We can then reason that the superposition must also satisfy the ODE.

**But is there a way to derive directly from the ODE, without make the abovementioned educated guess, the general solution of that ODE?**

(I don't have much experience with second order ODE's).

Comment: You are asking how to derive the general solution **without** making the well known ansatz $y=e^{\lambda t}$ to obtain the [characteristic equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealRoots.aspx)?

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure what the characteristic equation of an ODE is exactly...

Comment: Here is an approach using the characteristic equation: Substituting $y=e^{\lambda t}$ into the ODE gives: $$\lambda^2 e^{\lambda t}=e^{\lambda t} \implies \lambda^2-1=0$$ Solving for $\lambda$ and using superposition gives the general solution. The reason I am not putting this up as an answer is because the substitution $y=e^{\lambda t}$ is technically a guess. If you are satisfied with this, I can put this up as an answer.

Comment: How generally applicable is this guess $y=e^{\lambda t}$? would it apply to $\delta _{tt} y=-y$? (I'm assuming $\lambda$ would be complex in that case). would it apply to all linear (inhomogonous?) equations?

In any case, no my question was whether it's possible to do without such a guess. Basically the reason I'm asking is to find out more about how to solve second order ODE's using generally applicable methods. with first order ODE's there are such methods (e.g. separation of variables)

Comment: The substitution would apply, then one can use Euler's formula: $$e^{i\theta}=cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$$ It is applicable for **second order linear homogeneous equations with constant coefficients**. To do it without using the guess, you can integrate both sides twice.

Comment: integrating both sides twice gives me: $\frac{\delta ^2 y}{\delta t^2}=y\implies \frac{\delta y}{\delta t}=C+\int y(t)dt\implies y(t)=Ct+\int \int y(t) dt dt$. That doesn't help right?

Comment: If you factorize the differential equation via $0 = (\partial_t^2 - 1)y(t) = (\partial_t - 1)(\partial_t + 1)y(t)$, in effect you "split it" into two 1st order ODEs.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=y$$
Here is how to do it without using the characteristic polynomial (Using the ansatz $y=e^{\lambda t}$). Note that the characteristic polynomial method is a **lot easier** but this is a method without any guesses.

---

If you multiply both sides by $\frac{dy}{dt}$, you should obtain: $$\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=y\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}$$ Integrating both sides with respect to $t$ gives: $$\int \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}~dt=\int y\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}~dt$$
One can integrate the LHS by substituting:
$$u=\frac{dy}{dt} \iff du=\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}~dt$$
As a result, we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{y^2}{2}+c_1 \tag{1}$$

---

It remains to solve the first order ODE. Be careful to not forget the case when $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is negative!
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{y^2+2c_1}$$
It is a separable ODE:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+2c_1}}~dy=\int \pm dt$$
Integrating both sides gives:
$$\ln\left(\sqrt{y^2+2c_1}+y\right)=c_2\pm t$$
Now, one can rearrange this to obtain two explicit solutions for $y(t)$:
$$y(t)=\frac{e^{t+c_2}-2c_1e^{-t-c_2}}{2} \tag{2.1}$$
$$y(t)=\frac{e^{-t+c_2}-2c_1e^{t-c_2}}{2} \tag{2.2}$$
Redefining the arbitrary constants for both cases $(2.1)$ and $(2.2)$ gives the same general solution!
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y(t)=Ae^t+Be^{-t}}$$

Comment: Note that this technique can in principle be used to solve any ODE of the form $y'' = f(y)$ (assuming the desired integrals exist in closed form and can be inverted in the last step.)  In physics, this technique has a nice interpretation in terms of kinetic and potential energy (though given your username, I suspect you already know that.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Could you explain that interpretation?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD:  Not in fully 600 characters, but a brief sketch:  suppose an object has a force acting on it that is a function of (1-D) position only:  $F(x) = m a = m \ddot{x}$.  This is an ODE of the form I gave above.  If you follow the steps to get to eq. (1) in the above answer, you can be interpret the result as (kinetic energy) = - (potential energy) + constant.  In other words, energy is conserved.  You can then use the energy conservation equation to try to solve for the particle's trajectory $x(t)$ (though you can't always write a solution in closed form.)

Comment: For more details, I like Chapter 4 of Taylor's *Classical Mechanics*.

Comment: How did you go from $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+2c_1}}~dy $ to $ \ln\left(\sqrt{y^2+2c_1}+y\right)$?

Comment: Substitute $$y=\sqrt{2c_1}\tan(u) \iff dy=\sqrt{2c_1}\sec^2(u)$$
You will obtain:
$$\int \sec(u)~du=\ln(\tan(u)+\sec(u))+C$$
After resubstituting, use the fact that:
$$\sec(\arctan(z))=\sqrt{z^2+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to motivate the introduction of the characteristic equations associated to the ODEs with *constant* coefficients is by noticing that such differential equations can be factorized exactly as the polynomials. For example, in the given example,
$$0 = (\partial^2_t - 1)y(t) = (\partial_t - 1)(\partial_t + 1)y(t) \ ,$$
we can "split" the original 2nd order ODE into two simpler 1st order ODEs, $y'(t) - y(t) = 0$ and $y'(t) + y(t) = 0$. Each of them is easy to integrate and the solutions are, respectfully, $y_1(t) = A e^t$ and $y_2(t) = Be^{-t}$, with some constants $A$ and $B$. Finally, both $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are solutions of the original ODE since each of them is "killed" by one of the operators, $\partial_t - 1$ or $\partial_t + 1$.

Comment: Could you explain why we can treat the derivative operator as if it were a number, as you're doing? Why is it valid to turn $(\delta^2_t-1)y(t)$ into $(\delta_t-1)(\delta_t+1)y(t)$, and then to conclude that those two first order ODE's must hold simultaneously? What is the justification for that?

Comment: First note that $(\partial_t - 1)(\partial_t + 1)y(t) = (\partial_t - 1)(y'(t) + y(t)) = y''(t) + y'(t) - y'(t) - y(t) = y''(t) - y(t)$. I do not claim that those two 1st order ODEs must hold *simultaneously*, just that it is enough to find solutions for each of them and these will immediately solve the original 2nd order ODE (because the operators $\partial_t - 1$ and $\partial_t + 1$ commute).